# How to create a policy function which can only show same department id records in HR.EMPLOYEE

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a policy function that wants to select the same department ID's record. Suppose that only the logged-in user who is in EMPLOYEES table can SELECT the same records in the same department ID.
And first I have to check the logged-in user's department ID and return where condition for further policymaking. For example, I am `DGRANT` and I logged into the PDB, suppose I can get my DEPARTMENT_ID in EMPLOYEES table by using the policy function. But I can't.

From below is my function code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hide_other_department
(
    v_schema_name IN VARCHAR2,
    v_object_name IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
    where_condition VARCHAR2(200);
    v_dpt_id  EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE;
    current_user_name VARCHAR2(255) := 'DOCONNEL';
BEGIN
    SELECT user INTO current_user_name FROM dual;
    SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID INTO v_dpt_id FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE EMAIL IN (current_user_name);
    where_condition := 'DEPARTMENT_ID = ''||v_dpt_id||''';
    RETURN (where_condition);
END hide_other_department;
/
```

I want to get the logged-in username first using
`SELECT user INTO current_user_name FROM dual;`
and perform a select query in EMPLOYEES to get the logged-in user's department ID. But I cannot do that cause I am using `system` account to login and compile the function. And it returns me the below error messages.

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
9/15      PLS-00201: identifier 'EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID' must be declared
9/15      PL/SQL: Item ignored
13/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
13/45     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
Errors: check compiler log
```

When I use the `HR` account to compile my function. I can compile it but with errors.

[EMPLOYEES table content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b52e.png)
In the EMPLOYEES table, suppose the EMAIL column's value is the same as login username.

Please help me with the function codes. Thanks.

Comment: I am little confused , you have mentioned two problems. Which one do you want to resolve ? Please also share the the policy script which you have used to apply it ? 3. Is the where condition `WHERE EMAIL IN (current_user_name)` correct ? Did you try the function with just hard coding one particular department ?

Comment: My policy script is attached, ```hide_other_department```.

The main problem I wanna solve is that I want to create a policy script to select only records within the same department as the user.

Comment: Where do you mean , it is attached ? could you add sample data as well with owner information which would help in providing a solution ?

Comment: Maybe i update the my post first.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 i have upload the EMPLOYEES' table content. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. Does this usernames in `EMAIL` column are database users ? why I am asking is when you select `SELECT user FROM dual` it does give the `user_name` you have used to login to access the database.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Yes, the usernames in ```EMAIL``` means the database users.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then - if you're trying to create that function using `SYSTEM` account (think twice! Is that a good idea) - then you should precede object names with their owner's name, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hr.hide_other_department        --> hr.
...
v_dpt_id   hr.employees.department_id%type;                --> hr.
...
```

Comment: I can compile it without using ```hr.``` but still I cannot run it because there are errors in my function... I still cannot figure it out. If I use ```hr.```, I will encounter PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following: